# Why some relative clause can be reduced and some can not?

Tags: grammar, clauses

I am learning the book named *Grammar and Vocabulary for Advanced* by Martin Hewings and Simon Haines. I am struggling with the grammar relating to relative clauses. Could you please help me clarify the relative clause in below two sentences?

1. Under the new government proposals, from next year electricity suppliers will have to provide the devices—**which have cut** power use by up to 6.5% in Canada—to all customers who want them. (Can this sentence be  written like this :  Under the new government proposals, from next year electricity suppliers will have to provide the devices— **cutting** power use by up to 6.5% in Canada—to all customers who want them.)
2. However, the monitors, **which use** microchip technology and a digital play, are intended to be placed in full view as a constant reminder of the electricity that is being used in a house at any given moment. (This sentence can be written like this :  However, the monitors, **using** microchip technology and a digital play, are intended to be placed in full view as a constant reminder of the electricity that is being used in a house at any given moment.)

Could you help me explain why sentence 1 **"which have cut"** can not be replaced by **"cutting"**? Is it because of the present perfect used **"have cut"**. For sentence 2, **"which use"** is reduced by **"using"**.

Comment: Does your book say that you can't do so? As for the reason you're looking for, *the devices cutting power use by 6.5% in Canada* is not the same thing as *the devices which have cut power use by 6.5% in Canada*.

Comment: What @Stockfish said. The original text says those devices ***have already cut power usage*** in Canada (a "completed" action). Your alternative would mean they were ***in the process of cutting power usage*** (an ongoing action). Obviously there's a semantic difference, which you may or may not think is significant in any given context.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation Stockfish and FumbleFingers.

Comment: Relative clauses are tensed. When they are converted into participles, the tense is lost, because participles are tenseless. So one never knows what the original tense would be. Often this doesn't matter, because tense usually doesn't matter. But occasionally it is important, like the first example.

Comment: thanks so much John Lawler!